# Formattable: How to create a super column with several sub-columns under in R?

Tags: r, formattable

I am trying to create a table using `formattable` with a super column and several sub-columns. Right now, I was able to create two columns for `variable_units` and `site`. But I would like to move `site` (as a super column) above the two minimum time columns. How do I do that?

[image]

I only managed to get this far and the code is still not working.

```
 min_time.table <- formattable(
  variable.min.2,
  align = c("l", "l", "l"),
  list(
    area(col = "Site") ~ " ",
    area(col = "Minimum_Years_80_Correct") ~ normalize_bar('pink', max = 100),
    area(col = "Minimum_Years_100_Correct") ~ normalize_bar('pink', max = 100)
  )
)
```